# Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, oop

Why the examples about hibernate use **SessionFactory interface** instead **SessionFactoryImpl class** to open a session on the given connection?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation could change? In general, if you can use an interface to interact with an object, you should. Interfaces are less likely to change than classes, so if a class conforms to the interface, always reference it BY the interface. This is pretty standard OOP practice.